# show fields in get all django panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new at django panel, I want to show some particular fields in the index method but I see "NameClass Object" intead. I tried using fields and list_display but it didn't work.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from base_proyecto.models import *

class AutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fields = ('name', 'dob', 'hp')
  list_display = ('name', 'dob', 'hp')


admin.site.register(Autor)
```

[image]

I want to see multiple columns, one per attribute. It should look like this

- | name    | dob       | hp |
- J.Ken    08/04/1994   20
- J.Ken2   08/01/1994   25

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Auto` model you must define a `__str__` (for python 3) or `__unicode__` (for python 2) method. Like this:

```
class Autor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # other fields here

    def __str__(self):  # python 3
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):  # python 2
        return self.name
```

Comment: _unicode_ works but I want to show multiple fields. I edited the question in order to be more clear

Comment: No problem! Just `return '{field1} {field2} {field3}'.format(field1=self.field1, field2=self.field2, field3=self.field3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `__unicode__()` method if you're on python 2 or `__str__()` if you're on python 3, for your model.

Comment: I edited the question. Let me know if the question is clear

Answer (score 0):

Write the **unicode**() method in `Author` model(or **str**() if you're using Python3),

```
class Author(models.Model):
    # Here fields stuff

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nomber  

class AutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Author
     fields = ('name', 'dob', 'hp')
    list_display = ['name','dob', 'hp']
```

**edit** : - if you want to return multiple values then try this

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.name, self.dob, self.hp)
```

Comment: yes __unicode__ works but how can I show multiple fields?